# understanding strlen function in C

Tags: c

I am learning C. And, I see this function find length of a string.

```
size_t strlen(const char *str) 
{ 
 size_t len = 0U; 
 while(*(str++)) ++len; return len; 
}
```

Now, when does the loop exit? I am confused, since str++, always increases the pointer.

Comment: FYI: Read Kerningham and Richie. They have introduced this style of programming. A word of precaution though is never to use this style in commercial applications.

Comment: I have that book, but first using other resources to get comfy with C :)

Comment: @user439578: What does style (any style) have to do with type of application? Just use the style you like better and `indent` (with house style) before submitting the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. C strings are terminated by the `NUL` character which has the value of `0`
2. 0 is `false` in C and anything else is `true`.

So we keep incrementing the pointer into the string and the length until we find a `NUL` and then return.

Comment: I knew the the first point. The second made it clear!! Thanks

Comment: I am ok with your answer, but for the mentioning of ASCII. Would be better to leave that out. `nul` is guaranteed to be `0` with any encoding.

Comment: @Jens amended as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 12):

```
while(*(str++)) ++len;
```

is same as:

```
while(*str) {
 ++len;
 ++str;
}
```

is same as:

```
while(*str != '\0') {
 ++len;
 ++str;
}
```

So now you see when `str` points to the `null` char at the end of the string, the test condition fails and you stop looping.

Comment: "is same as:" except for the final value of `str`, but that's unused in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand two notions to grab the idea of the function :

1°) A C string is an array of characters.

2°) In C, an array variable is actually a pointer to the first case of the table.

So what strlen does ? It uses pointer arithmetics to parse the table (++ on a pointer means : next case), till it gets to the end signal ("\0").

Comment: table of characters? Do you mean array of characters?

Comment: Yep. I always make this mistake in english (in french, we say "tableau" for "array", so I tend to go with "table").

Answer (score 0):

Once `*(str++)` returns 0, the loop exits. This will happen when `str` points to the last character of the string (because strings in C are 0 terminated).

Answer (score 0):

Correct, `str++` increases the counter and returns the previous value. The asterisk (`*`) dereferences the pointer, i.e. it gives you the character value.

C strings end with a zero byte. The `while` loop exits when the conditional is no longer true, which means when it is zero.

So the `while` loop runs until it encounters a zero byte in the string.